# Fetching href of a link

Tags: python, lxml

I am using lxml and python. I want to fetch the **href** for the link that reads **More reviews (‎40)** on this [page](http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=2860002122405830765). I am basically scrapping this site and want to get the reviews.

Would appreciate the help. Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link is added using client-side javascript. So you cannot get the href using normal HTML parsing. You can however look at the javascript code and get the link from there:

```
>>> import re
>>> import urllib2
>>> import lxml.html
>>> page = urllib2.urlopen("http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=2860002122405830765").read()

# have to search the page source since the link is added in javascript
>>> mo = re.search(r'<div class="pp-more-reviews">.*?</div>', page)
>>> div = lxml.html.fromstring(mo.group(0))
>>> href = div.find("a").attrib["href"]
```

Other options are:

1. Use [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to control a real browser.
2. Use the [phantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) headless browser

Comment: if you could help me with the similar issue on the next page. I would like to fetch the line *X out of Y people found this review helpful*. This is under each review. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing it in the following way. Not very elegant but still solves the purpose

```
response = urllib.urlopen('http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=7101561317478851901').read()
dom = html.fromstring(response)
href = dom.find_class('pp-more-reviews')[0].find_class('pp-more-content-link')[0].xpath('@href')
```